# install google font local

Tags: magento2, fonts

I have got an information that I must install the used google font local.
I have checked my domain https://www.agoshop.at at https://www.ccm19.de and https://sicher3.de/google-fonts-checker/
I will get the following information to install the fonts local:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?display=swap&family=Lato:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?display=swap&family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?display=swap&family=Open+Sans%3A300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic,latin-ext
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v34/memvYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVTS-muw.woff2
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v23/S6u9w4BMUTPHh6UVSwiPGQ.woff2
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v23/S6uyw4BMUTPHjx4wXg.woff2
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLEj6Z1xlFQ.woff2
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJfecg.woff2
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v20/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLGT9Z1xlFQ.woff2
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v23/S6u9w4BMUTPHh7USSwiPGQ.woff2
```

I change in the Theme Settings Basic Font Family: Select Google Fonts to Select Custom Fonts but I use still google fonts.

Hope someone can help me how I can change now in my magento shop the google font links to local links.

kindly regards for any help

Comment: You can use https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/lato?subsets=latin, download used fonts, add them to css and remove fonts.googleapis.com link

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Where can I find the correct css file.
Kindly regards

Comment: `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/web/css/source/_typography.less`. See https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/css/fonts/